# Spring 3.0 HEAD Requests

Tags: http, spring, spring-mvc, controller, httprequest

recently we moved to spring 3.0 Controller handling like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
   protected String onSubmit ( Form form, Errors errors) {
        // handle POST
   }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   protected void getForm ( Form form ) {
     // handle GET
   }
}
```

Now we are getting lots of Exceptions in our logs because of HEAD Requests.

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodResolver.resolveHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:415)
    ...
```

I would like to support HEAD Requests the same way like GET Requests, but obeying the HTTP reference of course:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET
>   except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response.
>   The metainformation contained    in
>   the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD
>   request SHOULD be identical    to the
>   information sent in response to a GET
>   request. This method can    be used
>   for obtaining metainformation about
>   the entity implied by the    request
>   without transferring the entity-body
>   itself. This method is    often used
>   for testing hypertext links for
>   validity, accessibility,    and recent
>   modification.
>   http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Does anybody has an elegant solution or is there even a spring solution out-of-the-box?

I searched the web but did not find any answers to this.

Comment: What is making the HEAD requests? Could this be a mis-configuration on the client or client side code (Javascript)?
I am asking because usually HEAD is meant to check for updates to the page (i.e. Cache-Control / LastModified headers) so the browser can update is necessary.

Comment: PycURL does a request method = head for doing gets. Usually, I have found that this is very normal for lot search engines like : oneriot.com, ask.com etc..

Comment: who cares which tool is making HEAD Request. It is a valid HTTP Request and many browser are doing it actually (checking bookmarks or whatever).

Comment: According to below link spring should provide implicit HEAD and OPTIONS if they are not present for given request url, is it true from spring 4? or something else I am missing? [spring docs mvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options) is the link.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the current Spring (4.3.10) HEAD is automatically supported:

> @RequestMapping methods mapped to "GET" are also implicitly mapped to
>   "HEAD", i.e. there is no need to have "HEAD" explicitly declared. An
>   HTTP HEAD request is processed as if it were an HTTP GET except
>   instead of writing the body only the number of bytes are counted and
>   the "Content-Length" header set.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options

Comment: When clicking on the above link, for some reason, my browser drops the "-ann-requestmapping-head-options" portion of the anchor.  If this also happens for you, you can do a page search for "HTTP HEAD, OPTIONS" and get to the relevant section.

Comment: The link was fixed

Comment: This feature is available since Spring 4.3.0
This is the easiest ant proper way to solve this issue IMO.

Answer (score 21):

I believe this is what you're looking for:
http://www.axelfontaine.com/2009/09/transparently-supporting-http-head.html

Comment: After 5 years, is there a more elegant solution? As in less lines to add?

Answer (score 18):

Just add `HEAD` as a supported method the the request mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
```

Update: I think you can provide a custom class that extends `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` to be the method handler (in `dispatcher-servlet.xml`), and just bypass the HEAD support check there. But I'd just use the replace features of an IDE to add it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this solution is already known. But I don't like to add it a few hundred times. This is not what I referred to as an "elegant solution". But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Surely this would violate the specification that states 'The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.'?

Comment: @hoipolloi it depends on your web container. Apache Tomcat does automatically remove the response body for HEAD requests, for example.

Comment: This is the correct answer nowadays. Spring handles the `NoResponseBody` automatically if `RequestMethod.HEAD` is added.