# RequestMethod HEAD returns a response body

Tags: spring-boot

I have to implement HEAD method and as mentioned in 
[Spring 3.0 HEAD Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803015/spring-3-0-head-requests)
 .I have tried by adding adding a HEAD in request mapping and also by not adding it in the request mapping. Both the ways it is supporting HEAD method.

But the content length is not zero and i get the response body (image) as well.

```
    private static final String GZIPSUFFIX = "-gzip";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/version/url.json", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD })
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> testUrl(@RequestParam(value = "uri") String url,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) String size,
            @RequestParam(value = "type", required = false) String type, WebRequest webRequest,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        long startTime = 0;
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        }

        MediaFile mediaFile = retrieve(url, size);

        byte[] mediaContent;
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> result;

        ControllerUtils.addResponseHeaders(response);
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(getMediaType(url));
            mediaContent = mediaFile.getContent();
            result = new ResponseEntity<>(mediaContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

**Expected :** Content LENGTH TO BE 0 and no response Body

**Actual :**  Content length not zero and a response body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have indicated that you want to handle both `HEAD` and `GET` requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/version/url.json", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD })
```

This means that you also need to implement the different behaviour for `HEAD` vs `GET`. You can get the request's method by injecting `NativeWebRequest` rather than `WebRequest`. From the `NativeWebRequest` you can retrieve the underlying `HttpServletRequest` and from there the request's method via `getMethod()`. When `"HEAD".equals(getMethod())` you should return a `ResponseEntity` with no body.

A simpler solution is to only explicitly handle `GET` requests:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/version/url.json", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
```

Spring MVC will then implicitly handle `HEAD` requests for you by taking the response returned from your `testUrl` method and ignoring the body.

Comment: simpler solution is feasible. Although i have to do some custom things so i feel having a separate method for head would be better. Because if i rely on spring for Get and Head request, the amount of time spent on both would be same. Which i want to reduce by not retrieving the binary image.